# Changing rec location and width programatically

Tags: javascript, svg

I've the below code, which is drawing a `rec` in a `svg` element:

```css
.container
{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 1.3em;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <label for="from">From:</label>
    <input type="number" name="from">
    <label for="to">To:</label>
    <input type="number" name="to">
    <svg margin="0" width="200" height="1.3em">
        <rect x="10" y="0" width="30" height="1.3em" stroke="black" fill="green" />
    </svg>
```

I want to be able "prpgramatically" to:

1. Shift the location of the `rec` by changing the value of the `from` field
2. Chang the width of the `rec` by changing the value of the `to` field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const svgRect = document.querySelector('svg rect')


function xStart(XS){
  svgRect.setAttribute('x',XS)
}
function rWidth(RW){
  svgRect.setAttribute('width',RW)
}
```

```css
.container
{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 1.3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <label for="from">From:</label>
    <input onchange="xStart(this.value)" type="number" name="from">
    <label for="to">To:</label>
    <input onchange="rWidth(this.value)" type="number" name="to">
    <svg margin="0" width="200" height="1.3em">
        <rect x="10" y="0" width="30" height="1.3em" stroke="black" fill="green" />
    </svg>
```

For changing width, you can add even listeners to mouse position and situations, below sample code:

```js
        let svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
        svg.setAttribute("class", "octicon octicon-star");
      //  svg.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 14 16");
        svg.setAttribute("version", "1.1");
        svg.setAttribute("width", 240);
        svg.setAttribute("height", 160);
        svg.setAttribute("aria-hidden", "true");
        let barThickness = 20

        let orders = [100, 152];
        //orders.forEach((element, index, array) => console.log('a[' + index + '] = ' + element) )
        orders.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
            console.log('a[' + index + '] = ' + element)
            let r = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
            r.setAttribute("x", 0);
            r.setAttribute("y",(barThickness+10)*index+0);
            r.setAttribute("width", element);
            r.setAttribute("height", barThickness);
            r.setAttribute("fill","black");

            let isDrawing = false;
            let x = element
            let mousePosition = 0

            r.addEventListener('mouseenter', e => {
                e.path[0].setAttribute("fill","red")
            });

            r.addEventListener('mouseleave', e => {
                e.path[0].setAttribute("fill","black")
                if (isDrawing === true) {
                    isDrawing = false;
                }
            });


            r.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
                isDrawing = true;
            });

            r.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
                if (isDrawing === true) {
                    console.log(e.offsetX)
                    if(e.offsetX>mousePosition) {
                        x++
                    } else if(e.offsetX < mousePosition){
                        x--
                    }
                    mousePosition = e.offsetX
                    r.setAttribute("width", x)
                }
            });

            r.addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
                if (isDrawing === true) {
                    isDrawing = false;
                }
            });

            svg.appendChild(r);
            document.body.appendChild(svg) 
        
        }  )
```

Comment: Thanks, wonderful, is there a way to do same by `dragging` the rec for x point change, and dragging the right end of the rec to change its length?

Comment: I updated your answer by adding the answer of the second part of my question, now how can I joing both steps together?

Comment: you can use a library called 'snap.svg' to make it draggable , i have added anther answer using this library ,you can search for it for more information

Answer (score 0):

```js
   var startX = 100;
        var startY = 100;

        function init() {
            Snap("#rect").drag(dragMove, dragStart, dragEnd);
        }



        function dragStart(x, y, evt) {
            // figure out where the circle currently is
            startX = parseInt(Snap("#rect").attr("x"), 10);
            startY = parseInt(Snap("#rect").attr("y"), 0);
        }

        function dragMove(dx, dy, x, y, evt) {
            Snap("#rect").attr({
                x: (startX + dx),
                y: (startY + dy)
            });
        }

        function dragEnd(evt) {
            // no action required
        }
```

```css
   .container {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            height: 1.3em;
            position:relative;
        }
        
        svg {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left:420px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.5.1/snap.svg-min.js"></script>

<body onload="init()">

    <div class="container">
        <label for="from">From:</label>
        <input type="number" name="from">
        <label for="to">To:</label>
        <input type="number" name="to">
        <svg margin="0" width="400" height="400">
      <rect draggable="true" id='rect' x="10" y="0" width="30" height="1.3em" stroke="black" fill="green" />
  </svg>
    </div>
</body>
```